# About TSMessage

Tags: iphone, ios7

I Build a APP demo to my Iphone,but I found that TSMessage are not IOS7 style(blurry),why did it not IOS7 style？I see the source code said that the TSMessage will be IOS7 style if my OS version is 7.
Please tell me why,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you should provide more details with your question. Right now, one may just guess the correct answer. But: [this issue posted on the GitHub project page](https://github.com/toursprung/TSMessages/issues/82) may shed some light.